# Particle System, when using Play() and Stop() functions, not working after build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried making the thrusting particles for a rocket in my game, it works fine in the editor screen, but it just did not show up in the .exe file after the final build. For the blast effect on death of the rocket, I used the Instantiate() function to show the particles, and that worked after the build too, but for the rocket thrusting particles, I used the Play() and Stop() commands, which did not seem to work after build.

Moreover, I tried Instantiating the thrusting particles if the thrusting button is pressed, else destroying it, but it gave the error `the gameObject trying to be instantiated has already been Destroyed.`

I also tried debug logs to see if the code detects that the particles must play, I get the response, but the particles wouldn't show up on the screen. Play on Awake for the particle was unchecked too.

Here is the code for the thrusting:

```cs
void Thrust()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * forwardThrust);
            print("mainEngineParticles Playing.");
            mainEngineParticle.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            mainEngineParticle.Stop();
        }
    }
```

If I used Instantiate() function for thrusting:

```cs
void Thrust()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * forwardThrust);
            print("mainEngineParticles Playing.");
            Instantiate(mainEngineParticles, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(mainEngineParticles);
        }
    }
```

But as I said, this ^^ code lead to errors, saying `the gameObject trying to be instantiated has already been Destroyed.`

For the explosion in death, the Instantiate() function did not lead to any errors as I wasn't trying to 're-Instantiate' it after destroying it, like for the thrusting...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you call these functions? Is it in Update()? You need to make a simple timing planning, maybe with coroutines etc. 

But if you want to do it with a hold down your key just use Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode key).

Comment: yes, this is in the update function actually

Comment: also, I am a unity beginner, so I am not well acquainted with coroutines, but I will do some research